# Pass parameter value outside Itembuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i wonder if there is a way to pass (index) value outside item builder

```
 PageView.builder(
   reverse: true,
   controller: PageController(initialPage: pageNumber ?? 0),
   itemBuilder: (_, index) {
     return Image.asset(Q.installQ()[index].address);
   },
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

"pass" the index, from where to where?  The index is iterating under the control of the builder to ensure the right elements are built for the current view.  What else would you want it to do?

Comment: i need to pass more data relate to the current index page in pageview to another widget
like : Text('${Q.installQ()[passedIndex].name}')

Comment: Sure.... call that from inside the itemBuilder callback, and index will be valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable outside the widget tree and then assign it to the index value like this

```
 PageView.builder(
        reverse: true, 
        controller: PageController(initialPage: pageNumber ?? 0),
        itemBuilder: (_, index) { 
            myVariable = Q.installQ()[index].address;
           return Image.asset(Q.installQ()[index].address); 
   }, 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass it to your itembuilder. But you can specify the index number of returning object. For example

```
return Image.asset(Q.installQ()[passedIndex].address);
```